# How do I include stand alone declarations in my Angular Project?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a tough time on google with this.

Essentially I am learning `WebGL2` and I am using `@types/webgl2` because at the time of writing, many of the WebGL2 declarations don't exist as part of any standard d.ts library.

Since Experiments are going into an Angular App, everything is looking good during development.

However, Angular CLI Fails to build with:

`error TS2304: Cannot find name 'WebGL2RenderingContext'.`

This appears specific and unlike a standard declaration. `webgl2` is not a module whereas other `@types` are.  Which is to say `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'` using `@types/pixi.js` works because the unicorns made it so.  However, `webgl2` is not a module. I can't import it since it augments built in browser API calls.

**Question**

How do I get Angular to see my declaration globally and is there any best practice to where this linking should go on a standard Angular CLI setup?

Comment: are the versions the same between the @types/webgl2  and webgl2 ?

Comment: As far as I am aware, typescript ships with `lib.d.ts` and in there or related is a `webgl` declaration.  However, there is no `webgl2` support.  The `@types/webgl2` are perfect, but I just don't know how to get Angular to see them.